# VBA <For/Next> - How is the MyString statement functioning in the code?

Tags: vba, loops, variant

There is example code in the Microsoft ODC that reads:

```
Dim Words, Chars, MyString
For Words = 10 to 1 Step -1
 For Chars = 0 to 9
 MyString = MyString & Chars
 Next Chars
 MyString = MyString & " "
Next Words
```

The purpose of this code is to show an example of the For...Next loop statements.

I am fairly new to programming, and I am not really looking for a full lesson on loops, but I would like to know how MyString functions in the code. I understand that it is a variant, but I don't quite understand why it is necessary for the variant to equal itself. Is this necessary because MyString is a string object/variant that outputs the number of the iteration of the loop?

Comment: Side note - this is a *very bad* example. There's no need to use `Variant`s here, and this is just bad practice. `Long`, `Long` and `String` should be used. Unfortunately the docs can sometimes not be the greatest.

Comment: In regards to why you are setting a string equal to itself, it is because you want to preserve the value currently stored in the string, while concatenating a new value to the end of it. A lot of languages have a special operator like ```+=``` to do that in a less verbose way, VBA does not.

Comment: @Warcupine knew this, but had forgotten...and you certainly jogged my memory. It is essential that I learn each piece of code logic before proceeding to the next steps in my learning process.